# XSLT Filtering to Prevent Self-Closing Tag in Rich Text Editor

Tags: 2013-sp1, rtf, component

I have problem in SDL Tridion 2013 rich text editor for Component, since it automatically convert an `iframe` tag to be self-close:

from `<iframe></iframe>`

to `<iframe/>`

I have looked for other similar cases but none of the solution works for me. Technically, the way is to make sure that there is something in between the opening tag and closing tag to prevent it to self-close.

Any proposed way to solve this?

Added: my current Filtering XSLT for the Component
`<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></output>
    <template match="/ | node() | @*">
        <copy>
            <apply-templates select="node() | @*"></apply-templates>
        </copy>
    </template>
    <template match="iframe">
        <element name="iframe">
            <apply-templates select="*"></apply-templates>
        </element>
    </template>
    <template match="*[      (self::br or self::p or self::div)     and      normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;     and      not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction())     and      not(comment())     and      not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])     and      not(following::node()[not(         (self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div)        and         normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*)        and         not(processing-instruction())        and         not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])       )])     ]">
        <!-- ignore all paragraphs and line-breaks at the end that have nothing but (non-breaking) spaces and line breaks -->
    </template>
    <template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
        <!-- Chrome generates <div><br/></div>. Renders differently in different browsers. Replace it with a non-breaking space -->
        <text> </text>
    </template>
</stylesheet>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the Schema RTF field, it usually has a XSLT fillter tab. This fillter uses `<xsl:copy>` which I have found leaves behind self closing tags.

The portion of the xslt that does this will look similar to

```
<xsl:template match="/ | node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"></xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

below this block of text add the block below

```
<xsl:template match="iframe">
   <xsl:element name="iframe">&nbsp;</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried this, but the iframe tag is still self closed. Any idea?

Comment: I have now edited the xslt to make it more specific to iframe, since you only want this for iframes,  with the correct xslt  you can get this done.

Comment: @AXT: Is that self-closing happening on CME Richtext Editor after you saving the component or after the publishing on the presentation side?

Comment: @Velmurugan, this self-closing is happened in the RTE, you have 3 tabs of design, source, and preview, and after you put your source (in this case the iframe tag), if you change to another tab and go back to source tab, it is formatted already as self-closed.

Comment: @Headoo, does it mean that I need to replace the codes in first block to the one specifically for iframe?

Comment: @AXT, no  just add it below it. if you remove it then you may have issues with every other tag in the RTF.

Comment: The problem is that a self-closing tag is perfectly valid in XML. It is up to the XSLT processor to decide if it should render an element as self-closed or not.
The work-around I use is to put a non-breaking space in the iframe. That forces the processor to render a separate closing element.

Comment: @Headoo, I added my XSLT filtering, but instead of making it not self-close, it omitted all the iframe parameters.

Comment: @AXT, like I said previously, you need the **correct XSLT**. You need the XSLT that suites your requirement. I have  edited  my XSLT,  but **note** that  this XSLT will only make sure you do not have self closing `<Iframe>`  If you have `<iframe>`  that is not empty it will make them empty So  think about your general requirement and add the XSLT that works for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways I can think of that you can tackle this issue:

- Update Tidy to parse `<iframe>` tag as block tag. For this I suggest you check [Nikoli's blog.](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/allowing-html-5-attributes-in-tridion-rich-text-fields)
- create HTML parser (some sort of C# code which can parse your HTML code and replace self closing tags with correct opening and closing tags) on publish time. Honestly, this is not the best approach, since parsing HTML is reaaaaaly tricky and hard at best, but you can identify all self-closing tags and override them. You can use regex like this to identify all self-closed tags:

> String regexString =
>   "<(?:\"[^\"]*\"[\'\"]*|\'[^\']*\'[\'\"]*|[^\'\">])+(\/\s*)>";

Please keep in mind that with this approach, your content will still have self-closed `iframe` tag, but its representation after publishing will be OK. Also, I would still go with option 1 if possible.

Comment: I am aware about option 1 which I can't take at the moment, because it will change all the RTF for all components to ignore any tags. I am looking for a solution where I can edit and filter it on certain schema within the RTF itself using XSLT filtering.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, a simple workaround to fix this issue.

- open the component and switch to the Source tab for component (not the RTF field), update as below and Save and Close Component.

> <iframe src="http://www.google.com"
>   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">&nbsp;</iframe>

Comment: this work only because this is not empty tag (because it has one empty space withing its tags). Tidy will do it. The only problem with this approach is that technically its not the same tag as empty iframe tag, so it can break your layout (with a single linespace)